# python django sort with lambda with if statement

Tags: python, django, lambda

I have date and some dollar gross model:

```
class FirstDate(models.Model):
    gross = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SecondDate(models.Model):
    gross = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And want to sort it by `gross`, and if `gross` is the same, then sort it with `updated` field

For example,

```
qs1 = SoloDate.objects.all()[:2]
qs2 = GroupDate.objects.all()[:2]

result_list = sorted(
    chain(qs1, qs2),
    key=lambda x: x.gross # and if gross is the same, for the gross same objects, x.updated and then update was also the same, x.pk,
    reverse=True
)
```

I mean, let me say that there is two objects individually from qs1 and qs2.

```
# objects from qs1
qs1_obj1 = {
'pk': 1,
'gross': 5,
'updated': 2018-11-24 10:53:23.360707+00:00
}

qs1_obj2 = {
'pk': 2,
'gross': 5,
'updated': 2018-11-25 10:53:23.360707+00:00
}

# objects from qs2
qs2_obj1 = {
'pk': 3,
'gross': 5,
'updated': 2018-11-24 10:53:23.360707+00:00
}

qs2_obj2 = {
'pk': 4,
'gross': 1,
'updated': 2018-11-23 10:53:23.360707+00:00
}
```

It's `result_list` order will be `qs1_obj1`, `qs2_obj1`, `qs1_obj2`, `qs_2_obj_2`.

Reasons is it:

`qs1_obj1`: 1.by gross, 2.by updated, 3.by pk,

`qs2_obj1`: 1.by gross, 2.by updated, 3. but pk was not good,

`qs1_obj2`: 1.by gross, 2.but by dpdated was late,

`qs2_obj2`: 1.gross was small.

Maybe it is not good question or bothersome question, I need help.

Question line is that :

```
key=lambda x: x.gross # and if gross is the same, for the same gross objects, x.updated and then update was also the same, x.pk,
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sorting by multiple fields like so:

```
result_list = sorted(
    chain(qs1, qs2),
    key=lambda x: (x.gross, -x.updated.timestamp(), x.pk) # and if gross is the same, for the gross same objects, x.updated and then update was also the same, x.pk,
    reverse=True
)
```

Comment: Thank you but I think, it seems that I need there `reverse updated`. Because last updated one come as first. How can I do this? `-x.updated` returns line: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: @touchingtwist I've updated the answer. datetime is now converted to timestamp which is an integer.